# Hive code stuck in reduce=99%

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, skew

I run a paragraph of hive code. But it stuck in 99%.
here is my code below:

```
    insert overwrite table novaya.brand_info 
select goods.brandid, goods.brandnm, cate1.cate1_price, cate2.cate2_price, cate3.cate3_price
  from novaya.goods_info goods 
    left join 
    (select brandid, brandnm, mng_catecode1, avg(sales_price) as cate1_price
    from novaya.goods_info  where brandid is not null 
    group by brandid, brandnm, mng_catecode1) cate1 
    on goods.brandid=cate1.brandid
    left join 
    (select brandid, brandnm, mng_catecode2, avg(sales_price) as cate2_price
    from novaya.goods_info  where brandid is not null 
    group by brandid, brandnm, mng_catecode2) cate2
    on  goods.brandid=cate2.brandid
    left join 
    (select brandid, brandnm, mng_catecode3, avg(sales_price) as cate3_price
    from novaya.goods_info  where brandid is not null 
    group by brandid, brandnm, mng_catecode3) cate3  
    on goods.brandid=cate3.brandid
  where goods.brandid is not null ;
```

The logic is not complex that the cate1, cate2 and cate3 will be appdendix their columns after brandid and brandnm which belong to the goods table. Goods table may be more larger than the three tables.
It may caused by skew. And how can I fix this problem without changing hive settings.
Mant thanks.

Comment: row counts of tables? do you really need all tables to be joined without any filtering criteria (where clause)?

Comment: In addition to row counts, also count the distinct keys (if this is significantly lower, you may be exploding the amount of rows in the output). -- How long is it stuck? -- Does the query work if you use it on 10 rows of data, or 1%? (and what appears to be the complexity?)